# Sync API or Datastore API for database backup

Tags: android, dropbox

I am thinking of using dropbox to provide capability for users to backup the local SQLite Database and restore it back. Basically  I want to copy the db file to dropbox when backing up and copy it back when restoring.

To do this , which API should I use ? Sync API or Datastore Api? Any code example is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: See this link :

It is a similar question with a solution..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583242/skydrive-dropbox-sync-for-files-database-in-android?rq=1

Comment: For db file copy purpose, use sync API. For individual record sync, use Datastore API, but Dropbox Datastore will also keep data locally offline.. so, storage consumption will be increased.